# bounding the lat lng with osmdroid similar to LatLngBounds in google maps

Tags: android, osmdroid

In my android application I'm using routing and clustering in osmdroid but I'm not able to bound the LatLng like we do in google maps with latlngbounds.builder...

for example

```
LatLng longlat = new LatLng(lat, log);

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(longlat);
```

I want to do the same with osmdroid.

Comment: Are you talking about osmdroid? Please mention at least the library you are using.

Comment: yes i am talking about osmdroid

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps LatLngBounds becomes BoundingBox in osmdroid (more or less).

It has no direct equivalent to the LatLngBounds.including method (yes, could be a good idea to implement this one).

But BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints covers a lot of needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
IGeoPoint screenTopLeft = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0, 0);
            IGeoPoint screenTopRight = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(), 0);
            IGeoPoint screenBottomLeft = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0, mapView.getHeight());
            List<IGeoPoint> iGeoPoints = new ArrayList<>();
            iGeoPoints.add(screenTopRight);
            iGeoPoints.add(screenTopLeft);
            iGeoPoints.add(screenBottomLeft);
            BoundingBox boundingBox = BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(iGeoPoints);
            if (boundingBox.contains(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This will check whether current location is under bound or not.